# Django: Search URL for keyword RegExp

Tags: python, regex, django

I have the following URL:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/databaseadd/q=DQ-TDOXRTA?recipe=&recipe=&recipe=&recipe=&recipe=`
I'd like to match if the keyword "recipe=" is found in the url.
 
I have the following line in django url.py but it's not working:
 
`url(r'recipe=', 'plots.views.add_recipe'),`

Are the  "&" and the "?" throwing it off?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part after the `?` not used in the url dispatching process because it contains GET parameters. Otherwise you will not be able to use a GET request with parameters on patterns like `r'^foo/&'` (ampersand at the end means the end of the string, and without it it would be harder to use patterns like `r'^foo/'` and `r'^foo/bar/'` at the same time).

So for your url the pattern should look like `r'^databaseadd/q=DQ-TDOXRTA&'` and then in `add_recipe` view you need to check for the `recipe` GET parameter.

Comment: The problem is that what's after the q= is a variable. The "DQ-TDOXRTA" portion will change and will not be a consistent length. Is there a good way to get around that? I'd like to load a new view when I get both q= and recipe= in the URL.

Comment: Then the pattern will be `r'^databaseadd/q=(?P<q>[A-Z\-])&'`.`'DQ-TDOXRTA'` will be passed to the view as `q` argument. As for the new view it will be easier to define separate function and just call it if both parameters exist.

Comment: Assuming q contains capital letters  and dashes. Otherwise change the `[A-Z\-]` part.

Comment: You mean, create a call to another function within the view, right?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to match if the keyword "recipe=" is found in the url

You could try something like :

```
import re;
re.match (r'.*recipe=.*', "http://127.0.0.1:8000/databaseadd/q=DQ-TDOXRTA?recipe=&recipe=&recipe=&recipe=&recipe=")
```